# Unable to install Codename one iOS debug app

Tags: ios, iphone, codenameone

I have an app that is already in store, now I'm busy making some changes and I want to test on device before submitting an update to store.

After the changes I sent a debug build for iOS. When I try to install the app on my device, nothing happened, not even the usual dialog that reads **codename-one.appspot.com would like to install "App name"** was shown.

I also try installing the app through iTunes on my Mac, but failed to install.

I got an error as well using iFunbox.

What is wrong with my App? I have other apps using the same debug certificate and are being installed successfully without a hassle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An app that was initially installed through App Store can not be override with a debug app, even if it's of higher version.

To solve this, the store app on the testing device have to be removed first and you will be able to install the debug app.

Comment: why not just changed the identifier?

Comment: That's a very good point. Though if I change the identifier I will have to create an additional Provisioning profile to allow the new  identifier. I will do this moving forward. Thanks.

Comment: Now Xcode handle the provisioning thing for you most of the times if you logedin

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that, unfortunately I'm using Codename one cross-platform dev tool... Codename one also helps in adding new devices, generating provisioning profiles and certificates. https://www.codenameone.com